# Create EPG URL from Json in android for IPTV application

Tags: android, json, iptv

i am developing **IPTV** application for android, getting Json data after logging it, but dont know how to create EPG from json in android. I have to open IPTV Core application description as [Github](https://github.com/AlexanderSofronov/iptv.example). Although i have opened the application but unable to get channels.

Any Help could be appreciated Thanks in advance.

Comment: EPG From json??? if it available in input json data you can use it but if do not exist...then you could not be able to use it1!

Comment: plase post you trying code and output